# Filenames not showing in git diff

Tags: git, bash, windows-10

Using 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' on Windows 10 (Insider Preview), git version 1.9.1

I've used `git diff` a million times on other machines, but on this particular setup it's not showing filenames. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The blank white space at the top is missing the usual ---a/file +++b/file among other things. I ran  `git config --list` to see if there might be some configuration issues but there are only a few entries in there that aren't related to branches and source locations:

[image]

I'm getting these results from both Bash and from cmd. Why might this be happening?

Comment: To clarify:  you didn't erase that section before posting it, it's actually just whitespace?  Is it really _whitespace_ or is it white-on-white text?  Can you select it in the terminal and copy/paste?  What happens if you upgrade to a more modern version of Git for Windows?  https://git-for-windows.github.io

Comment: Good call here, the color was white on a white background

Comment: Thanks! been searching everywhere on how to change just the *filename* color  for a `git diff` ! (meta is close enough!!!)  ..Sooo glad I found *your* question.  Accepted answer is Just what I've been looking for !! **+1 to both of you :)**

Comment: Ha! I forgot you are *both* the *same person*, lol. Well, double points from me to you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others pointed out, there actually were characters being displayed, it was just a color issue - The background and the font color were both white.

It is possible to configure the font colors for most git output and, in the `git diff` case, you can actually change the color of different sections of the output. To change the color of the top section (the 'meta' section) of the output, use the following command:

`git config --global color.diff.meta "blue"`

You can omit the `--global` if you only want the changes to affect the current session and user, and you can use different colors.

This is a sample output with the color set to 'magenta':
[image]

More details can be found here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Search "meta" or "color.*" in the linked document to get directly to the section detailing color options for "meta"  *Thanks soooo much!! @s-g*